# Before filter security concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently on my projects I have a way to check if the user has id of "1", he gets allowed access to certain action. I have used devise gem for authentication.

Here is my code reference

```
before_filter :find_xxx, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy, :create, :new]
```

and here is the code

```
  protected    
def find_xxx
  if user_signed_in? && current_user.id != 1
      redirect_to "/", :notice => "Not today"
  end
end
```

I looked at the official Rails docs, and they approached it in similar fashion. I was wondering is this the safe way to protect my action, Can't someone just add form into my html with /post to either action, to perform the action.

What is the best way to protect my methods.

Thanks for your time and consideration. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have Devise authentication working properly, such that `current_user` is authenticated, no one will be able to sneak past authentication by manipulating forms before submitting them.

You'll want to reverse the logic in your filter, though, because as it stands users will be able to bypass the redirect simply by not signing in to begin with (because `user_signed_in?` will be `false`).  If you've got another filter or authentication requirement that forces them to sign in before accessing any action in the controller, that may be sufficient.

Just to be safe, I'd change the conditional to:

```
unless user_signed_in? && current_user.id == 1
```

Note that it's generally not a great idea to rely on a specific database ID like this.  You're better off [creating an admin role](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role) and/or using a gem like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to create more explicit security.

You should always write tests around things like this to ensure security.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation.